# Update only params that exist rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, parameters

I'm aware I can do something like this:

```
@object.update_attributes(date: params[:date]) if params[:date].present?
@object.update_attributes(date: params[:name]) if params[:name].present?
@object.update_attributes(date: params[:thing]) if params[:thing].present?
@object.update_attributes(date: params[:item]) if params[:item].present?
```

But is there a way to do all of this at once?
Something like:

```
@object.update_attributes(object_params)
```

where it won't put nulls in my database if they aren't passed in through the url. So I can call 
`Object.update(date: Date.today, name: "ryan")` and it will only update these items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just select `params` which are not `nil` in your controller and use `@object.update_attributes(object_params)` as usual

```
def object_params
  params.require(:object).permit(:date, :name, :thing, :item).select { |k, v| !v.nil? }
end
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this

`@object.update_attributes(params)`

Also, it's a good practice to use strong params, putting this in the end of your controller

```
  private

    def object_params
      params.require(:object).permit(:date, :name, :item, :thing)
    end
  end
```

and use it as

`@object.update_attributes(object_params)`

Comment: I do use strong params and tried this but it didn't work

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
keys = [:date, :name, :item, :thing]
object_params = params.slice(*keys).delete_if { |k,v| v.nil? }
@object.update_attributes(object_params)
```

You could also do this if the param keys match the model columns:

```
object_params = params.slice(*Model.column_names).delete_if { |k,v| v.nil? }
@object.update_attributes(object_params)
```